# Automatically apply module patch and compile kernel when updated?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, upgrade, kernel-modules

I've recently applied a one-line patch to `drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c` in order to enable compatibility with my Bluetooth device. However, whenever I get a kernel upgrade, the patch will be lost until someone backports it (which isn't likely). Is there a way for me to run a script and patch each new kernel upgrade automatically?

DKMS seems like a good solution, but I'm not sure how to set things up. I don't want to recompile the entire Linux kernel every time I get an update, but I'd like to apply that patch to the btusb module, recompile it, and insert it into my kernel on every update. How can I do this using the source obtained from `apt-get source linux-source-3.2.0`? What files do I need to copy over? The critical `make` call is `make M=drivers/bluetooth modules`, but this depends on other kernel utilities to be built first. How can I assemble a DKMS module for this?

<sup><sub>Details on how to apply the patch can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/226646/6645) on Ask Ubuntu.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should package up your changes as a DKMS module. Building modules for several installed kernels or automatically rebuilding them on an updated kernel is the main feature of DKMS.

Ubuntu community documention has a nice article on this topic [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS).

Comment: Could you give an example of how to configure DKMS for my specific use case? For example, what files do I need to copy over for my module? How should I configure dkms.conf?