# Using DKMS, to automatically patch and install kernel on update

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I have a system that needs patching a file in kernel to work properly. The system is running Ubuntu 14.04.

The patch patches a file in `drivers/hwmon`.

So after every kernel update I need to download the kernel sources, apply the patch, rebuild the kernel and install it.

Essentially, my question is very similar to [Automatically apply module patch and compile kernel when updated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58229/automatically-apply-module-patch-and-compile-kernel-when-updated) , where using DKMS is suggested. There is a link to general DKMS docs provided, but it doesn't cover the situation of patching a module.

Could you please show me how to configure DKMS to perform the patching automatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Patching a module does not really change the way. What you basically need is to put all files you need to compile an out-of-tree build of your particular kernel module into a folder `/usr/src/<modulename>-</moduleversion>/` and you need to add a configuration file `dkms.conf` into that folder.

Basically it should look like this:

```
MAKE="make -C $kernel_source_dir M=\$(pwd)"
PACKAGE_NAME=hwmon
PACKAGE_VERSION=1.2.3.4
BUILT_MODULE_NAME[0]="hwmon"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/kernel/extra"
AUTOINSTALL=yes
```

For patches, you should have a look at the [man page for dkms](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/manpage.html) linked to below, as an excerpt:

> ```
>    PATCH[#]=
>           Use  the  PATCH directive array to specify patches which should be applied to
>           your source before a build occurs.  All patches are expected  to  be  in  -p1
>           format  and  are  applied  with the patch -p1 command.  Each directive should
>           specify the filename of the patch to apply, and all patches must  be  located
>           in  the  patches  subdirectory  of  your  source  directory  ( /usr/src/<mod‐
>           ule>-<module-version>/patches/ ).  If any patch fails  to  apply,  the  build
>           will  be  halted  and  the rejections can be inspected in /var/lib/dkms/<mod‐
>           ule>/<module-version>/build/.  If a PATCH should only be  applied  condition‐
>           ally,  the  PATCH_MATCH[#]  array should be used, and a corresponding regular
>           expression should be placed in PATCH_MATCH[#] which will alert dkms  to  only
>           use that PATCH[#] if the regular expression matches the kernel which the mod‐
>           ule is currently being built for.
>
>    PATCH_MATCH[#]=
>           See the above description for PATCH[#] directives. If you only want  a  patch
>           applied  in  certain  scenarios,  the PATCH_MATCH array should be utilized by
>           giving a regular expression which matches the kernels you intend  the  corre‐
>           sponding PATCH[#] to be applied to before building that module.
> ```

Then you want to register it with dkms, build and install the module

```
dkms add     -m hwmon -v 1.2.3.4
dkms build   -m hwmon -v 1.2.3.4
dkms install -m hwmon -v 1.2.3.4
```

I've used placeholders for module name and version, but you should get the idea. This is all covered in the [man page for dkms](http://linux.dell.com/dkms/manpage.html).

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it in January and thn mark your answer as accepted.